# como consumir este Array que vem da API no react com typeScript?

Tags: javascript, array, json, react

```
[
  {
      "ssId": 420090,
      "statusSS": "Reservado",
      "dataInicialVoo": null,
      "pendencias": [
          {
              "id": 2418,
              "ssId": 420090,
              "observacao": " Verifique se todos os passageiros foram inseridos na etapa SBSP(1) Verifique se todos os passageiros foram inseridos na etapa SBBR(2)",
              "statusSS": "Reservado",
              "altaPrioridade": null,
              "dataAgendamento": null,
              "dataInicialVoo": null,
              "tipoId": 3,
              "tipo": "Passageiro",
              "usuarioResponsavelNome": "user",
              "usuarioResponsavel": "user",
              "usuarioCriacaoNome": null,
              "usuarioCriacao": null,
              "dataCriacao": null
          },
          {
              "id": 2416,
              "ssId": 420090,
              "observacao": "Pendente De acordo",
              "statusSS": "Reservado",
              "altaPrioridade": null,
              "dataAgendamento": null,
              "dataInicialVoo": null,
              "tipoId": 1,
              "tipo": "De acordo",
              "usuarioResponsavelNome": "user",
              "usuarioResponsavel": "user",
              "usuarioCriacaoNome": null,
              "usuarioCriacao": null,
              "dataCriacao": null
          },
          {
              "id": 2419,
              "ssId": 420090,
              "observacao": "Soma dos pagamentos diferente do valor da planilha",
              "statusSS": "Reservado",
              "altaPrioridade": null,
              "dataAgendamento": null,
              "dataInicialVoo": null,
              "tipoId": 4,
              "tipo": "Pagamento",
              "usuarioResponsavelNome": "user",
              "usuarioResponsavel": "user",
              "usuarioCriacaoNome": null,
              "usuarioCriacao": null,
              "dataCriacao": null
          },
          {
              "id": 2417,
              "ssId": 420090,
              "observacao": "Verificar se comissaria foi validada",
              "statusSS": "Reservado",
              "altaPrioridade": null,
              "dataAgendamento": null,
              "dataInicialVoo": null,
              "tipoId": 2,
              "tipo": "Comissaria",
              "usuarioResponsavelNome": "user",
              "usuarioResponsavel": "user",
              "usuarioCriacaoNome": null,
              "usuarioCriacao": null,
              "dataCriacao": null
          }
      ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -2):

Seria bom uma melhor descrição do seu problema, mas, se você quer fazer a tipagem desse array de objetos ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
interface Pendencia {
  id: number;
  ssId: number;
  observacao: string;
  statusSS: string;
  altaPrioridade?: string | null;
  dataAgendamento?: string | null;
  dataInicialVoo?: string | null;
  tipoId: number;
  tipo: string;
  usuarioResponsavelNome: string;
  usuarioResponsavel: string;
  usuarioCriacaoNome?: string | null;
  usuarioCriacao?: string | null;
  dataCriacao?: string | null;
}

interface MyObjType {
  ssId: number;
  statusSS: string;
  dataInicialVoo?: string | null;
  pendencias: Pendencia[];
}

const myObj: MyObjType[] = [
  {
    ssId: 420090,
    statusSS: "Reservado",
    dataInicialVoo: null,
    pendencias: [
      {
        id: 2418,
        ssId: 420090,
        observacao:
          " Verifique se todos os passageiros foram inseridos na etapa SBSP(1) Verifique se todos os passageiros foram inseridos na etapa SBBR(2)",
        statusSS: "Reservado",
        altaPrioridade: null,
        dataAgendamento: null,
        dataInicialVoo: null,
        tipoId: 3,
        tipo: "Passageiro",
        usuarioResponsavelNome: "user",
        usuarioResponsavel: "user",
        usuarioCriacaoNome: null,
        usuarioCriacao: null,
        dataCriacao: null,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```